# Update Cells of Main Google Sheet With New Form Response Values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried searching, but was unable to find a good example.

- I have a main Google Sheet in which the primary key is an ID number. Each ID number should only have a single record (row). There are some column values that are populated, some that are empty, and no set pattern as to which are populated. We need to allow this sheet to be editable.

- I have a separate Google Form that captures data. The responses are
  logged on a tab in the main workbook.

- I would like a script to be able to run on a trigger in which I set a
  column drop down to "completed" and it copies values to the main
  sheet based on the primary key thus updating the main sheet values
  only where there is new information.
- There will be columns that the form is not intended to update, so we
  cannot replace an entire row.

I have found examples that can move and copy entire rows, but the form will not contain all of the values of the main sheet so this will not work.

I do not want to have to add rows to the main sheet and delete old rows. I only want the relevant new values from the form to be populated in the appropriate columns. It would be great if I could specify which column number I would a value to be inserted into. I have attached a screen shot of what this would look like below and sample sheet/form

I have been using a copy of [Hyde's Move Rows script](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/39992635?msgid=40432488&sjid=1965583420556104343-NA)  for moving entire rows, but I do not think it can be configured for this use case.

Here is my [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YNtYPoni_dC3p5OBuPE1ddzIKgkruOiRJ9Jx1RQ4-yQ/edit?resourcekey#gid=0)
and here is my [sample form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1oC84bcPX-k6RMtuN5tKh-ZckXtPE7CVKChzBnrxgKLc/edit)

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use Installable Trigger (On Form Submit)

To achieve your goal, you must:

1. get the latest entry from the response tab,
2. search the Main Sheet for duplicates (using `indexOf()`),
3. process the latest entry by either adding a new row (if the entry is new) or overwriting the corresponding existing row with the same id as the new entry.
4. make the function an installable trigger with `on form submit` option.

Since you have not provided a sample spreadsheet, I have created a test case spreadsheet for this post.

### Script

Here is a sample script that I made for my sample test spreadsheet:

```
function processFormData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1"); //name of the form response sheet tab
  var outSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Main Sheet"); //name of the main sheet tab
  var latestData = formSheet.getRange(formSheet.getLastRow(),3,1,formSheet.getLastColumn()-2).getValues(); //gets the latest entry from the form responses
  var id = outSheet.getRange(1,1,outSheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); //gets all the values in the id column as basis for the search
  var searchIndex = id.flat().indexOf(latestData[0][0])+1; //returns the row of the existing entry with the same id as the new entry. returns 0 if the new entry has no duplicate.
  if (searchIndex != 0) {
    latestData.map(x=>x.map((y,j)=>{
      if (y!='') {
        outSheet.getRange(searchIndex,j+1).setValue(y); //overwrites entries with the same ID as the new entry
      }
    }));
  }
  else {
    outSheet.getRange(outSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,latestData[0].length).setValues(latestData); //adds a new row for the new entry
  }
}
```

You may change the sheet names to the appropriate names of your sheet tabs.

### Installable Trigger Setup

Afterwards, you must setup the installable trigger as shown below: [image]

### Output:

Using my initial test data:

[image]

I entered the following sample data:

[image]

After hitting the submit button, I got the following changes:

[image]

### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Update

To tailor fit the script to the sample form and sheet that you have provided, I have modified the script (by changing the parameters of `getRange()`) as follows:

```
function processFormData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1"); //name of the form response sheet tab
  var outSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Main Sheet"); //name of the main sheet tab
  var latestData = formSheet.getRange(formSheet.getLastRow(),2,1,formSheet.getLastColumn()-1).getValues(); //gets the latest entry from the form responses
  var id = outSheet.getRange(1,1,outSheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); //gets all the values in the id column as basis for the search
  var searchIndex = id.flat().indexOf(latestData[0][0])+1; //returns the row of the existing entry with the same id as the new entry. returns 0 if the new entry has no duplicate.
  console.log(latestData)
  if (searchIndex != 0) {
    latestData.map(x=>x.map((y,j)=>{
      if (y!='' && j && 2 && j != 4) { //add the additional condition here (using AND statement and index j) to avoid overwriting specified columns.
        outSheet.getRange(searchIndex,j+1).setValue(y); //overwrites entries with the same ID as the new entry
      }
    }));
  }
  else {
    outSheet.getRange(outSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,latestData[0].length).setValues(latestData); //adds a new row for the new entry
  }
}
```

Comment: Please feel free to ask if you have any questions with respect to the answer provided above.

Comment: Sorry for only including a screenshot. Here is a link to my sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YNtYPoni_dC3p5OBuPE1ddzIKgkruOiRJ9Jx1RQ4-yQ/edit?resourcekey#gid=0 and here is a link to the sample form: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1oC84bcPX-k6RMtuN5tKh-ZckXtPE7CVKChzBnrxgKLc/edit Your solution almost works, but does not copy over the first column which is the record ID number

Comment: Oh, ok. i see now. the difference is that in my form response, there is an additional email column. Let me modify the script I provided.

Comment: I have added a script to the `Update` section to my answer. Please try it and see if it works. I have used the same installable trigger setup.

Comment: What would I do if there are columns I do not want to overwrite that are in the middle of the order ex: columns C and E above?

Comment: I have added a comment to the script to guide you.

Comment: If you wish to add more columns to the exceptions, you may need to base the index value of the array value of `latestData` using `console.log(latestData)`

Comment: I tried the recent script and get the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRange')"

Comment: That just means that your sheet is blank. The script runs fine on my side.

Comment: Got it, there was a typo in the name. Is there any reason why it does not copy Field 6 and Field 7 for ID row 1, but does for the other rows?

Comment: I assumed row 1 is reserved for the headers? Also, I had corrected a mistake earlier, the script should have used `AND ( && )` and not `OR ( || )` to add exempted columns.

Comment: Thanks, the && solved the problem! What I meant was that in the sheet there is an ID of 1 (row 2) in the responses. When I update that ID with the values in field 6 and 7, but not as a new entry it does not populate those fields, however, it does for IDs 2 and so forth (row 3 to row N)

Comment: That is weird, i too have an ID of 1 in row 2 on my test case and when I tried to edit the contents using the form, the updates were applied correctly. Could you please share the file you are using so that I may try the script there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255319/discussion-between-kwalker-and-patrickdc).